# Handling questions from non-English writers?

Tags: discussion

We're seeing an increase in questions from people who clearly have trouble with English language. This question is a place to collect ideas about how we *can* help, within the limits of the system. A place we can point people to when they're having trouble asking a question that makes sense. In a sense this could be a FAC, *Frequently Added Comments*, to non-english speakers.

> *Read this page in another language: http://itools.com/tool/google-translate-web-page-translator*

Answer (score 10):

Finding the right words in a foreign language is difficult, especially on technical subjects. However **we simply *can't* help without adequate information** about what you are trying to accomplish. If words can't be found, some small drawings might help.

If that's not possible for whatever reason, I believe you'll have to wait until the community grows large enough to attract more members using your native tongue to help in **[Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939)**. The site itself will always be english.

Answer (score 7):

People on various listservers (c. 1990s), on the ESRI forums (last decade), and here have always shown a willingness to overlook obvious language problems and help people.  In some cases--we have seen a spate of them recently--there seems to be a difficult combination of extreme language difficulty and extreme lack of GIS knowledge.  There have to be limits; we cannot expect to help people who are too deficient both in the technical background and ability to communicate.  If one thing in the FAQ can help with this, it would be pointers to introductory, basic GIS material in other languages.

Answer (score 3):

users that can't write in english have one tool that is relatively good:

http://tradukka.com

it translates a wide range of languages and the translation to english from the several languages is, as far as i know, very reasonable (better than google).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the services like google translator or any other language translators the non-english users can share questions and answers. but their will be some limitations. what my point of view is, the vision and mission behind stack exchange is to share ideas, solve problem etc for anyone at anytime. so we member should take some initiative to help the non-english member when they post.