# Why is there nothing about having to write your questions/answers in English in the "Tour" or "Help Center"

Tags: discussion, internationalization

I've noticed while commenting on questions/answers asking them to rewrite their question/answer in English that there is nothing to link toward for them to check out the "rule" in the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) or the [Help Center](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help).

Even in the 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), language is not mentioned.

Then in
[Why do I see a message that my question does not meet quality standards?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error), It states:

> Correct use of English spelling and grammar to the best of your ability.

However, the server does not automatically block non-English questions based on quality standards. This seems weird to me.

So my question is the following: Is there a reason that the rule about only using the English language is not mentioned anywhere? and should it be explicitly written that questions, answers, and comments have to be in English?

Answer (score 1):

We have very little scope for modifying the Tour or Help Center content.

However, we do have a Meta GIS SE FAQ on [Handling questions posed in a Language Other Than English (LOTE)?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3236/115).

Also, I just added a sentence into [this answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115) to our FAQ on [Asking good questions for GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3349) which says:

> Questions and their titles must be written in **English**.

Comments are temporary and while English is preferred for those too, I think there is some scope for them to be made in other languages to try to assist non-English speakers when necessary.

Comment: Well, that is kind of a shame. I read that link before posting my question, but the problem I have with it is it is not quick/simple/easy to find for a new user and it is not geared toward the new user asking a question but reviewers. So it is not really a good material to link to explain the reasoning for the english only policy. but https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy might be good though more generic and programming/code centric

Comment: @LouisCottereau we are always open to proposals that suggest the words and where to use them in order to improve our Tour and Help Center.